# How to expand the reciprocal of the distance between two points as an infinite sum of the product of two functions?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given two points $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$,the reciprocal of their distance is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+ (x_2-y_2)^2+ (x_3-y_3)^2}}$.

And I want to expand it in the form of infinite sum of the product of two functions, i.e.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+ (x_2-y_2)^2+ (x_3-y_3)^2}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3)g_i(y_1,y_2,y_3) $$
I have no idea how to tackle this, could someone help me?

Comment: Yeah, this is related to the Legendre polynomials, try looking there

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Applications_of_Legendre_polynomials